# Angular / Facebook : The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags

Tags: angular, facebook, facebook-graph-api, metadata, meta-tags

i have provided all the meta tag for facebook and twitter for my site.
Developing the site in angular:
Also provided xmlns .

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
```

Can someone please let me know what i am missing here.

On Facebook debugger , i am getting message as

> Inferred Property : The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Missing Properties :The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id

```
  updateTitle(title?: string) {

    if (!title) {
      this.router.events
        .pipe(
          filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
          map(() => this.activatedRoute),
          map((route) => {
            while (route.firstChild) { route = route.firstChild; }
            return route;
          }),
          filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary'),
          mergeMap((route) => route.data)).subscribe((event) => {
            this.titleService.setTitle(event['title']);
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: event['description'] });
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'author', content: event['author'] });
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'keywords', content: event['keywords'] });
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'news_keywords', content: event['news_keywords'] });

            //Indexing / Spiders 
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'googlebot', content: "all" });
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'bingbot', content: "all" });
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'robots', content: "all" });

            //OpenGraph

            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:type', content: "article" });
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:site_name', content: 'kadakfeed.com' });
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:title', content: event['title'] });
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:description', content: event['description'] });
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:url', content: this.url + event['url'] });
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:image', content: this.imgUrlPath + event['url'] + "/" + event['img'] });
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:image:width', content: "600" });
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:image:height', content: "340" });
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'fb:app_id', content: "2152587131722996" });



            //Twitter
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:card', content: "summary_large_image" });
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:site', content: "@kadakfeed" });
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:title', content: event['title'] });
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:description', content: event['description'] });
            this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:image', content: this.imgUrlPath + event['url'] + "/" + event['img'] });

          });
    } else {
      this.titleService.setTitle(title);
    }
```

}

In app.component.ts i am calling the meta service updateTitle()

```
constructor(public metaService: MetaserviceService) {
    this.metaService.updateTitle();

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Open Graph protocol's key is wrong, You have to use `property` instead of `name`

http://ogp.me/#structured

```js
/* the key value is wrong

this.meta.updateTag({
  name: 'og:type',
  content: "article"
});

*/

this.meta.updateTag({
  property: 'og:type',
  content: "article"
});
this.meta.updateTag({
  property: 'og:site_name',
  content: 'kadakfeed.com'
});
....
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: i have tried that but some how my meta tags are  not getting called.

Comment: like what, Isn't `og:XXX` create into your HTML?

Comment: somehow this subscribe((event) event is always undefined

Comment: Would you create an online example?(like http://stackblitz.com)

Comment: http://www.kadakfeed.com/amazons-jeff-bezos-and-wife-mackenzie-announce-divorce

please refer this link.. i have checked with inspect. it is showing all og meta tags but in facebook debug they are not getting reflected.

Comment: You have to use Server Side Rendering(https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/seo-angular-part-1-rendertron-meta-tags/)

Comment: I have tried the server side rendering.. but still  it not reflecting the default value that i have mentioned in index.html

Comment: http://www.kadakfeed.com/10-iconic-cafes-in-pune-to-relive-the-history

Comment: [URL returned a bad HTTP response code](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kadakfeed.com%2Famazons-jeff-bezos-and-wife-mackenzie-announce-divorce&locale=en_US). It has to be 200

Comment: yes i have checked that.. when i inspect it using debugger. it is showing the actual url but during facebook debugger it is always showing my home page.
what i read ,i understood that the url should always be  your actual url

Comment: I added two pictures to show your problem